# Oracle SQL Developer "command not properly ended" error in syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm working on some SQL developer queries and I keep getting this error. Ive looked online but I cant see to see why my syntax bring a "SQL command not properly ended error". The error is showing up on the line that has "FROM lgemployee as e". Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT e.emp_num, emp_lname, emp_fname, sal_amount
FROM lgemployee as e
NATURAL JOIN lgsalary_history
WHERE sal_from = (SELECT min(sal_from))
FROM lgsalary_history as s2
WHERE (e.emp_num = s2.emp_num)
ORDER BY e.emp_num;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `as` as alias for tables, only in select statements, for instance:

```
select column as "alias"
from table a
```

Remove the `as` from your table declarations. It should run fine.

Comment: Ok, I did that but for some reason it is only giving me one person. But at least im getting closer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just wrong parentheses nesting -- try

```
SELECT e.emp_num, emp_lname, emp_fname, sal_amount
FROM lgemployee as e
NATURAL JOIN lgsalary_history
WHERE sal_from = (SELECT min(sal_from)
FROM lgsalary_history as s2
WHERE (e.emp_num = s2.emp_num))
ORDER BY e.emp_num;
```